# Extract properties from indexed data in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have trouble understanding the possibilities of tokenizers and analyzers in Elasticsearch.

Suppose there is a set of indexed data of products. Each product has a field with a description text. In the description a color is named.

Is it possible to use one of the built in analyzers or a custom tokenizer/analyzer to extract that color information (eg. based on a set of keywords [red,green,blue,yellow etc.]) and attach that new color information as a separate field to the product?

Would be a nice feature to augment incoming data with generic properties (eg. colors, material etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process you describe has more to do with entity recognition. There are different libraries that do that give a text: [OpenNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org/), [UIMA](http://uima.apache.org/) and more.

You might want to have a look at the [elasticsearch OpenNLP plugin](https://github.com/spinscale/elasticsearch-opennlp-plugin), which does exactly what you want: detects entities and adds corresponding fields to the incoming documents.